# Convert the format of array in php

Tags: php, arrays

I have the data in the array form as:

```
0 => a,
1 => b,
2 => c,
3 => d,
4 => e,
5 => f,
6 => g
```

How can I convert these array into the following one?

```
0 => array(0 => a, 1 => b),
1 => array(0 => c, 1 => d),
2 => array(0 => e, 1 => f),
3 => array(0 => g, 1 => null)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

## [Live DEMO](http://phpfiddle.org/main/code/1ymx-r692)

Consider this code:

```
$j = 0;
for($i=0; $i< count($arr); $i++){
    if(($i !=0) && (($i % 2) == 0)){
        $j++;
    }
    $newArray[$j][] = $arr[$i];
}

$lastElement = count($newArray) -1;
if(count($newArray[$lastElement]) < 2){
    $newArray[$lastElement][]= null;
}
    
echo "<pre>";
print_r($newArray);
```

Output:

```
Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [0] => a
            [1] => b
        )

    [1] => Array
        (
            [0] => c
            [1] => d
        )

    [2] => Array
        (
            [0] => e
            [1] => f
        )

    [3] => Array
        (
            [0] => g
            [1] => 
        )

)
```

Answer (score 2):

User [**array_chunk()**](http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-chunk.php) function to split an array into chunks, and 2<sup>nd</sup> param chunk size

```
array_chunk($arr, 2);
```

Answer (score 1):

Chunk will not give `null` as requested in case if number of elements is aliquant.

```
$by = 2;
$arr = range('a', 'g');
$arr = array_merge($arr, count($arr) % $by ?
       array_fill(0, $by - count($arr) % $by, null) : array()); 
var_dump(array_chunk($arr, $by));
```